# CSS to Expand Space Between Text Hyperlink and Its Underline

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink, blogger

Is there a way to expand the space between letters and underlines in text-based hyperlinks using CSS?

The CSS I'm planning to use is:

```
.post-body a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

My blog is hosted on Blogger and uses the Simple template - http://nickalive.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

No, not using standard `text-decoration` settings.

What you **can do** is replace the underline with a pseudo-element which you can customise to your heart's content.

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  margin:1em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:-12px; /* changes distance from text */
  width:100%; /* width of underline */
  height:5px; /* height of underline */
  background: red; /* color or underline */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">My hyperlink</a>
```

[**Text-Decoration @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Comment: I've just tried it on my testing blog. It's worked, but the code is making hyperlinked images have underlines, too. https://imgur.com/a/FIwHLfQ - Is there a way to only have text links underlined?

Comment: No...you'd need to give those links a different style.